# How to put semicolons and date at end of the every line in generated text file through the windows batch script

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, merge

I have `file1.sql` and `file2.sql`; I have merged these into a `merged.txt` file.
I have written batch script like below:

```
@echo off
merged.txt (for /r "." %%F in (*.sql) do (type "%%F" 
    echo(
)   
)
)
```

**Output file (`merged.txt`) looks like:**

```
stored proc1

stored proc2
```

The merged file contains two lines because I am merging two `.sql` files.
Now I want to put the semicolon and date at the end of every line.

**So I am expecting output (`merged.txt`) file with Semicolon  like below:**

```
stored proc1; date

stored proc2; date
```

Pls help how can we put in the batch script.

Thank you

Comment: An example of the output you're currently getting, and the output you WANT to get, would be very helpful in understanding the question and how best to help you. Providing the inputs, and expected outputs makes it easier for people to provide you with an accurate answer to your question.

Comment: Do all `.sql` files contain merely one-liners or could contain a multi-line `sql` statement(s)? Please explain: _I want to put the semicolon at the end of every line **and dates**_.

Comment: To clarify you want a script that reads merged.txt and appends the current date to end of each line. Each line ends in a  semicolon ";"?

Do any lines in mergedt.txt contain a "%" ?

Comment: No. actually every .sql file ends with "END" key word..When this merged into merged.txt need to put ";" and date at eod line.

Comment: Requirement bit changed ,Date is not required at all lines at eol. I reached my required script. The changed script is,                                  
   @echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set storedProcLastExecution= Stored Procs Last Execution Date Time is:
set /a count = 0
echo --%storedProcLastExecution% %DATE% %TIME%>> merged.txt
echo %message_dec2% >> merged.txt
for /r "." %%F in (*.sql) do (
 set /a count += 1
    echo %message% !count!. %%F>> merged.txt
    type "%%F" >> merged.txt
                echo ;>> merged.txt
    )